# Is Possible to change an index sorting type from ascending to descending without dropping the index?

Tags: oracle, indexing

So I have created an index named IDX_TEST on table TEST,
`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "IDX_TEST" ON TEST ("ID")`

then I want to change the sorting type of the index from ASC to DESC,
can we achieving that without dropping the current index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `alter index` to change the sort order. For that you have to create a new index. If you cannot allow to don't have any index for that column at any time and you would like to have the same name for that descending index you could:

1. create the new index with temporary name,
2. drop the old index,
3. and then alter your index with descending order to change it's name.

Below you've got all possible options for alter index (for Oracle 21c):

```
ALTER INDEX [ schema. ]index
  { { deallocate_unused_clause
    | allocate_extent_clause
    | shrink_clause
    | parallel_clause
    | physical_attributes_clause
    | logging_clause
    | partial_index_clause
    } ...
  | rebuild_clause
  | PARAMETERS ( 'ODCI_parameters' )
               )
  | COMPILE
  | { ENABLE | DISABLE }
  | UNUSABLE [ ONLINE ] [ { DEFERRED | IMMEDIATE } INVALIDATION ]
  | VISIBLE | INVISIBLE
  | RENAME TO new_name
  | COALESCE [ CLEANUP ] [ ONLY ] [ parallel_clause ]
  | { MONITORING | NOMONITORING } USAGE
  | UPDATE BLOCK REFERENCES
  | alter_index_partitioning
  }
  ;
```

It's worth to mention that ascending index can be read in descending order, so overall having an index in descending order only benefits in a few cases.